# htaccess - redirect a directory including the index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am updating a website and having updated a directory name, I need to update all links for the old directory named `blog` to the newly named `press`

I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /press/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Which works perfect for any url's within that directory. i.e

```
website-url.com/blog/post-1
```

Goes too

```
website-url.com/press/post-1
```

However the blog index page still doesn't. I instead get a 404 when going to:

```
website-url.com/blog
```

If I have a trailing slash, it does work. Just not without.
I know I can use an absolute path redirect like so:

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://www.website-url.com/press
```

But the domain could change so I want to keep the path relative / dynamic for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /press$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This will match `/blog` also as `/.*` part is optional match.